# adding data to xml is giving error

Tags: oracle

I am using a plsql block which has below code and is giving a error to me at  in if condition.

error:- ORA-31020: The operation is not allowed, Reason: Invalid pl/sql DOM handle

```
PROCEDURE add_to_xml(
    p_doc         IN OUT dbms_xmldom.domdocument ,
    p_node_parent IN dbms_xmldom.domnode ,
    p_table       IN xml_tabtype )
IS
  k_routine CONSTANT VARCHAR2(255) := gk_package||'add_to_xml';
  l_stmt    VARCHAR2(512);
  l_node_child dbms_xmldom.domnode;
  l_txt_node dbms_xmldom.domnode;
  l_elem dbms_xmldom.domelement;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN p_table.first..p_table.last
  LOOP
    l_elem              := dbms_xmldom.createelement( doc => p_doc , tagname => p_table( i ).tagname );
    l_node_child        := dbms_XMLDom.appendChild( p_node_parent , dbms_XMLDom.makeNode( l_elem ));
    IF p_table( i ).val IS NOT NULL THEN
      l_txt_node        := dbms_xmldom.appendchild( l_node_child , dbms_xmldom.makenode( dbms_xmldom.createtextnode( p_doc , p_table( i ).val )));
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('error in add_to_xml'||SQLCODE||sqlerrm);
END add_to_xml;
```

can you please why this error pop ups ?

I have debug this and before if condition I have all the relevent data comming through this procedure.My database version is 11.

THe calling code is

```
declare
t_xml_tab                      xxcu_hr_interface.xml_tabtype;
l_doc                          dbms_xmldom.domdocument;
      l_top_node                     dbms_xmldom.domnode;
      l_node_top_detail              dbms_xmldom.domnode;
      l_node_assignment_change       dbms_xmldom.domnode;
      l_node_hdr_assignment_hdr      dbms_xmldom.domnode;

begin
t_xml_tab.delete;
           t_xml_tab(t_xml_tab.count + 1).tagname := 'OperasjonsID';
           t_xml_tab(t_xml_tab.count).val := 'U'; --Defect 1047
           t_xml_tab(t_xml_tab.count + 1).tagname := 'BusinessGroupID';
           t_xml_tab(t_xml_tab.count).val := 101;
           t_xml_tab(t_xml_tab.count + 1).tagname := 'FirmaID';
           t_xml_tab(t_xml_tab.count).val := 984661185;
           t_xml_tab(t_xml_tab.count + 1).tagname := 'AnsattNr';
           t_xml_tab(t_xml_tab.count).val := 52022;
           t_xml_tab(t_xml_tab.count + 1).tagname := 'StartDato';
           t_xml_tab(t_xml_tab.count).val := xxcu_hr_common.conv_date('18-AUG-75');
           t_xml_tab(t_xml_tab.count + 1).tagname := 'SluttDato';
           t_xml_tab(t_xml_tab.count).val := xxcu_hr_common.conv_date('31-DEC-12');
           t_xml_tab(t_xml_tab.count + 1).tagname := 'Primaer';
           t_xml_tab(t_xml_tab.count).val := 'J';
           t_xml_tab(t_xml_tab.count + 1).tagname := 'IntegrationKey1';
           t_xml_tab(t_xml_tab.count).val := 11933;
           t_xml_tab(t_xml_tab.count + 1).tagname := 'IntegrationKey2';
           t_xml_tab(t_xml_tab.count).val := 123;
           t_xml_tab(t_xml_tab.count + 1).tagname := 'PersonKategori';
           t_xml_tab(t_xml_tab.count).val := 1;

           dbms_output.put_line('3.7');

           ---dbms_output.put_line('3.7.1 t_xml_tab'||t_xml_tab(t_xml_tab.count + 1).tagname );

           xxcu_hr_interface.add_to_xml(p_doc         => l_doc,
                                        p_node_parent => l_node_hdr_assignment_hdr,
                                        p_table       => t_xml_tab);

 --dbms_output.put_line(l_doc);
exception
when others then
dbms_output.put_line('The error is :'||sqlcode||sqlerrm);
end;
```

Comment: Can you post your code that calls this code?  Based on the error, the p_doc might not have been properly initialized.

Comment: this is the code calls this procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your document via the createdocument function before passing it into your procedure.

[DBMS_XMLDOM Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_xmldom.htm#i1121082)

Comment: I am already assigning a variable l_doc   of type                dbms_xmldom.domdocument and passing it to procedure.Actually this part of code runs properly with my old logic and I am trying to add new structure in my old logic where this part of code works fine.Then how is this giving error although I am using my old logic to built XML?